# GUI tools for Apache

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, apache2

Are there any GUI tools for configuring and monitoring Apache?

Answer (score 5):

I used this for a while, it doesnt have to many feature but it does it job for managing modules and virtualhosts.

> [Rapache](https://launchpad.net/rapache) is a simple tool for
>   remotely managing and configuring an
>   apache2 instance without having to
>   hassle around through configuration
>   files.

Comment: Rapache doesn't work on 10.04 and it doesn't look like it will be revived anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

You could user [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) that is a webapp for managing servers. This would also have the advantage of easy remote access.

> Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix. Using any modern web browser, you can setup user accounts, Apache, DNS, file sharing and much more. Webmin removes the need to manually edit Unix configuration files like `/etc/passwd`, and lets you manage a system from the console or remotely.

[image: Editing the configuration of an Apache virtual host]

Comment: Webmin is not recommended for use on Ubuntu (it was [removed from the Debian and Ubuntu repositories](https://answers.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/2873) because the way it works can cause problems when updating).

Comment: The Webmin/Ubuntu incompatibility [looks like](https://www.virtualmin.com/node/21110#comment-95551) an issue of the [past](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebMin).

Answer (score 2):

There is httpd support in Gadmin.

Packages are in the repos and more information can be found on [the website](http://mange.dynalias.org/linux/gadmintools-webpage/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another tool I found. Does not have all the bells and whistles but it is currently being updated. Highly Integrated Localhost WebServer Indicator 
https://launchpad.net/localhost-indicator

Answer (score 0):

you can use /plesk/whm/directadmin/cpanel they are the most popular gui management tools for web hosting.